# Is it possible to make transaction using wallet private key

Tags: transactions, bitcoin-core, bitcoind

I have a private key of a bitcoin wallet . Is there is any way i can check balance and make transaction using bitcoin core without importing private key.

Comment: @AdamMillerchip Is there is any way other than importing private key.

Comment: Yes, you can assemble a tax manually, and sign it with OpenSSL after converting the private key. This requires a lot of understanding of the internals of bitcoin. If you do not have this knowledge, then you can try to rely on public services, with the extremely high risk of getting robbed. This is why there are software wallets,  which keep you save when working on your local PC. There are many different wallets, have you tried some of them? What is your experience level?

Comment: Also having local tools, you can convert the private key via ECDSA tools to his public key, and with the public key look on Blockchain.info, what the balance is...

Comment: @pebwindkraft Thanks for the information. Could you provide me any reference link or it would be better if you could post answer

Comment: I have no link. But the descriptions from Andreas book „Mastering Bitcoin“. Highly recommended: „Bitcoin Explorer (bx) is a command-line tool that offers a variety of commands for key management and transaction construction. It is part of the libbitcoin bitcoin library.“ and there is „The Python library pycoin, originally written and maintained by Richard Kiss, is a Python-based library that supports manipulation of bitcoin keys and transactions“. Those tools are for the highly advanced users - you have been warned! :-)

Answer (score 1):

You can check and watch the balance by adding the address corresponding to the private key as a [watch-only address](https://bitcoin.org/en/glossary/watch-only-address), but it's impossible to make a transaction in Bitcoin Core without importing the private key.

Comment: He mentions he has the private key... so he could just import it, right?

Comment: If i have this private key : `KxytQNYV3NhXHqJCP2FCQAkmScX22b1WwyMnbxo*****Sb8Gr7fT` and i don't want to import it in bitcoin core. How can i get balance and make transaction.

Comment: @pebwindkraft he edited the question to specify he didn't want to import.

Comment: Got it ... saw his reply ...

Comment: @AjitSoman: If this is your real private key with only five symbols hidden, I suggest that you move your money immediately, as that is a very small search space and your money could easily be stolen otherwise.

Comment: @Murch this is not real private key . Could you provide me some suggestion based on my question

Comment: You can calculate the address from the private-key offline and then only import the address as a watch-only address.

Answer (score 1):

You can use an airgapped machine to derive the address and import it as a watch-only address to another instance. You could also use an airgapped machine or hardware wallet to sign a raw transaction offline.